# Using bash(cygwin) inside C# program

Tags: c#, bash, process, cygwin

i need to use bash shell "inside" C# program. I want to mimic user typing in interactive mode and running cygwin commands.

i created a process that runs bash and redirect stdin,stout and std error but i can;t get tty to work attached is a sample code that starts bash process and redirect the input/output.

the problem is that i don't have tty device. if i try to run tty command or stty command i receive error response

```
tty - not a tty 
stty - Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

i think the this is caused from `psi.UseShellExecute = false;`

i need to run cygwin and disable echo with stty -echo but to do this i need a tty device. how ca i create a cygwin bash shell with tty device and redirect the stdin, out and error ?

1) what am missing ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace shartCygwin
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Queue<string> ResponseQueue = null;
        private static ManualResetEvent ResponseEvent = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResponseQueue = new Queue<string>();
            ResponseEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Process bashProcess = new Process();

            bashProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe"; 
            bashProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--login -i ";  
            bashProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\cygwin\\bin";

            bashProcess.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CYGWIN"] = "tty";

            bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            bashProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            bashProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            bashProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

            bashProcess.Start();

            DataReceivedEventHandler errorEventHandler = new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorDataReceived);
            DataReceivedEventHandler outEventHandler = new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutDataReceived);
            bashProcess.OutputDataReceived += outEventHandler;
            bashProcess.ErrorDataReceived += errorEventHandler;
            bashProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            bashProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        static void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (ResponseQueue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
                    ResponseQueue.Enqueue(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
                    ResponseEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        }

        static void OutDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (ResponseQueue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
                    ResponseQueue.Enqueue(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
                    ResponseEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your program, and even though I see the "Inappropriate ioctl for device" error, I also see the cygwin bash prompt after that. What exactly is the issue? I removed the CYGWIN=tty line and I see that te output is raw, with the control codes being displayed.

Comment: @Hemlock - I think the key here, based on Kevin Mark's answer, is that you get to decide whether or not to use the echo, so does it really matter if you turn echo off/etc... And what motivation is there for trying to trick CYGWIN into using a TTY?

Answer (score 6):

This may or may not help you or anybody else who happens across this question. This is the answer given to the same exact question on the Cygwin mailing list.

```
> i created a process that runs bash and redirect stdin,stout and std error
> but I can’t get tty to work attached is a sample code that starts bash
> process and redirect the input/output.
> the problem is that i don't have tty device. if i try to run tty command or
> stty command i receive error response 
> tty - not a tty 
> stty - Inappropriate ioctl for device

> i need to run cygwin and disable echo with stty -echo but to do this i need
> a tty device. how can i create a cygwin bash shell with tty device and
> redirect the stdin, out and error ?

  Why exactly do you think you need to run stty and set the tty operating
parameters, when the bash process is quite plainly *not* connected to a tty,
it is connected to your C# application?

  It's your application that is in charge of I/O - if it doesn't want echo,
all it has to do is discard the stuff it reads from the process' stdout
instead of displaying it, in your OutDataReceived/ErrorDataReceived handlers.

>             bashProcess.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CYGWIN"] = "tty";

  Don't do this.  Win32 native processes don't understand Cygwin's tty
emulation, which is based on pipes.

    cheers,
      DaveK
```

Source: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-09/msg00637.html

Answer (score 2):

A side note, not a real answer, have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx

To answer the question:

Your not correctly handling the events... You need to look for e.Data == null in the event handler for Error/Output received.  Once both event handlers receive this event AND the process has terminated you are done.  Thus you wait on three handles, one to tell you the Process.Exited event fired, one to tell you the error output received null, one to tell you the output received null.  Be sure to also set:

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Here is the full answer redirecting output to current console:

```
    static int RunProgram(string exe, params string[] args)
    {
        ManualResetEvent mreProcessExit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ManualResetEvent mreOutputDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ManualResetEvent mreErrorDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(exe, String.Join(" ", args));
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.ErrorDialog = true;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = psi;

        process.Exited += delegate(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exited.");
            mreProcessExit.Set();
        };
        process.OutputDataReceived += delegate(object o, DataReceivedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if( e.Data != null )
                Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", e.Data); 
            else
                mreOutputDone.Set(); 
        };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += delegate(object o, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Data);
            else
                mreErrorDone.Set();
        };

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", process.StartInfo.FileName); 
        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        if (process.HasExited) 
            mreProcessExit.Set();

        while(!WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { mreErrorDone, mreOutputDone, mreProcessExit }, 100))
            continue;
        return process.ExitCode;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't have tty device.
if i try to run tty command or stty command i receive error response 
tty - not a tty
stty -  Inappropriate ioctl for device

i think the this is caused from psi.UseShellExecute = false;

i need to run cygwin and disable echo with stty -echo but to do this i need a tty device.

how ca i create a cygwin bash shell with tty device and redirect the stdin, out and error ?

Comment: Your problem is that stty -echo tries to set settings on a terminal but when you redirect stdout to another pipe this command does error out. The redirection code by csharptest.net does work for you but redirection and setting console related stuff prohibit each other. You should change your called skript to detect the case where the output is redirected e.g. by just calling stty -echo to check if you are redirected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just exec something like:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -li /cygdrive/c/<path-to-shell-script-location>/chmod-cmd.sh
```

And then latch onto the input and output.

OR use [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/).